# How to operate with function body without evaluation

Tags: output-formatting, hold

I have several functions (let `a[x]` and `b[x]`), defined as expressions with integrals and differentiations. I want to perform some manipulations with these expressions - for example, ask *Mathematica* to simplify `a[x] + b[x]` without evaluations of integrals. `Hold` doesn't works (as I tried) as I used to expand functions `a[x]` and `b[x]` first. I think, that I could replace `Integrate` and `D` with some meaningless heads `integrate` and `d`, and then expand functions with another meaningless symbol `x`, but I can't achieve this, because *Mathematica* tries first to perform integrations and fails.

Example:

```
a[t_] := Integrate[t, {x, -∞, ∞}]
b[t_] := Integrate[t^2, {x, -∞, ∞}]
a[t]+b[t]  (* this doesn't works, as it "evaluates" integrals; 
              I want to see simple sum *)
```

*ADDED:*
I want to see something like `myIntegrate[t, {x, -∞, ∞}]+myIntegrate[t^2, {x, -∞, ∞}]`. Really, *a* and *b* are more complicated, and they contain more than one integrals. I want Mathematica to perform expression simplification keeping integrals unevaluated. I could manually modify definition for *a* and *b*, but they are rather complicated, and don't want to keep two copies (one with Integrate, and one with some myIntegrate).

Comment: What's the result you'd like to achieve for your example?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Edited question, added an output example that I want to achieve.

Comment: @Yury As it looks after added explanation it seems me that you want to make unnecessary complication of the problem. In such a case as a first step I simply define the functions under the integrals (in your case t and t^2) and then operate with them, transforming and adding a Jacobian, if needed, but not integrating them. I integrate the result in a second step as soon as I am satisfied with the results of the first step.. My solution offered below is only useful, if you want to suppress the integration for the purpose of a demonstration, such as giving a talk.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this would be using  `Defer`  or `HoldForm`. For example, let us define the functions a and b as follows:

```
 a[t_] := Defer[Integrate[t, {x, -∞, ∞}]]
 b[t_] := Defer[Integrate[t^2, {x, -∞, ∞}]]
```

and

```
 a1[t_] := HoldForm[Integrate[Exp[-t], {x, 0, ∞}]]
 b1[t_] := HoldForm[Integrate[Exp[-t^2], {x, 0, ∞}]]
```

They both return unevaluated function. Then the function:

```
 mySum[expr1_, expr2_] := ReplacePart[expr1, {1, 1} -> expr1[[1, 1]] + expr2[[1, 1]]]
```

does the job.

```
mySum[a1[t], b1[t]]
```

The result looks as follows:

> [image]

The same will take place with the functions `a[t]` and `b[t]`